# Hibernate proxy id value

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I found some mentions of similar questions, but not this exact question.

For a HibernateProxy instance (lazy loaded), can the @Id annotated field be made to contain the actual id value.

I can see in a debugger that the ID is known, and contained in the associated LazyInitializer implementation. But why is it not also put in the corresponding ID field of the actual entity/proxy object?

The only way to do this is apparently an elaborate trick using getId() accessor method and @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY). It would be great if this could be avoided.

Comment: what do you mean the actual Id value? the id thats contained in the db?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. It would be easier to get at if it was actually injected in the proxy instance. (Without using getters and @AccessType annotation, etc.

Comment: but Hibernate actually stores the id in its Persistent Bags. If I remember correctly, you could actually get the full entity using: 
`session.get(child.getParent().getId())` Parent being the lazily initiated entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible and I would personally find it confusing that only the id is initialized in the proxy, while the other properties are always null (even after the proxy initialization).

The point of the proxy is to delegate all method calls to the target instance (except `getId` if property access is used for it). Proxy instance itself is **never** initialized.